# PhilZ Touch 5 problem

Tags: rooting, samsung, recovery-mode

I am trying to root my phone through PhilZ Touch 5 but I am getting this error.

Finding update package...

Opening update package...

Installing update...

Installation aborted.

press any key to continue.

I have a Samsung Galaxy S3 Mini VE running Android 4.2.2, with PhilZ Touch 5.

Comment: What Provider? Also, why not CF-Auto-Root it?

Comment: will u give me a link on how to CF-Auto root my phone?

Comment: It's an ODIN package. Download CF-Auto-Root(autoroot.chainfire.eu) (Use CTRL+ F and search Your build number, which you can find in settings > about phone) and download ODIN(odin.ownload.com). Put your device in download mode (Google it), open ODIN, Put the AutoRoot package in AP/PDA (Depends on ODIN version), and click START.